# why my node js is not getting connected to sql server?

Tags: javascript, sql-server, node.js

I am trying to connect to sql server using node js. I have installed the package mssql and using sublime text editor.
this is my node js code.

```
 var sql = require('mssql');

var dbConfig={
server:'CCI-LPT-21',
userName: 'sa',
password: 'sa123#',
port:1433,
options: {
    instanceName: 'MSSQLSERVER2K12',
    database: 'HRApp',
    debug: {
        packet: false,
        payload: false,
        token: false,
        data: false
           },
        }
  };

function getEmp()
{
//console.log(dbConfig);
var conn = new sql.Connection(dbConfig);
var req = new sql.Request(conn);

//console.log(conn)

conn.connect(function(err){
if(err){console.log(err);
    return;
}
req.query("select * from Team",function(err,recordset){
    if(err){
        console.log(err);
        return;
    }
    else
     {
        console.log(recordset);
     }
    conn.close();
   })
})

}

 getEmp();
```

when I run this from command promt,I get this error[image]

when I did Console.log(dbconfig) it was having this data

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your error it's you have to set `user` and not `userName`.

Check this example from the [doc](https://github.com/patriksimek/node-mssql):

```
var config = {
    user: '...',
    password: '...',
    server: 'localhost', // You can use 'localhost\\instance' to connect to named instance
    database: '...',

    options: {
        encrypt: true // Use this if you're on Windows Azure
    }
}
```

It's **user** and not userName.